# how to open mobile network(cellular) on react native

Tags: react-native

I want to open mobile network with a button in my react native app and then user can turn it on.

How can I open the mobile network?

How user can turn it on if there is no WiFi

Comment: I think I haven;t seen a mobile device (iOS, Android, Windows) which doesn't support bringing control center by swiping up or down from bottom/top of the device where the user can turn off/on his network settings. You can access this functionality inside most of apps. Wouldn't it be better to check for the connection/type of connection and react to that ?

Comment: I'll check connection/type
I just want to show this screen to the user so he can turn it on

Comment: For example I use this code to display wifi screen. DeviceSettings.wifi();